# Mailformed GitHub Plugin configuration (no protocol: )

Tags: jenkins

Whenever I do save on Jenkins(Manage Jenkins-> Configure System), I am getting the above error.
Can you please suggest the possible reason.

Comment: where are you seeing this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
In my case, the cause was wrong Jenkins URL setting.
Check Jenkins URL setting in http://{jenkins_server}/configure.

---

Reference

https://github.com/dboissier/jenkins-control-plugin/issues/30

The issue above is the only solution I have ever found.
And the suggestion is following.

> could you please run the following url :
>   YOUR_JENKINS_URL/api/xml?tree=nodeName,nodeDescription,primaryView[name,url],views[name,url,views[name,url]]
>
> Please go to your http://jenkins_server/configure and check the value
>   of Jenkins URL (located above Email Notification section). Normally
>   you should have your jenkins server url. If not, please fix it (unless
>   you need to keep the value ci/ and in that case, the plugin will not
>   work)